# Positon an Acitvity applied with a theme dialog at a particular x, y position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I would like to place the dialog on a particular position on the screen(-10px from top and -5px from let).

I did apply the theme and added the `android:scrollX`, `android:scrollY`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any solutuions?

Below is my styling xml.

```
<style name="Theme.MyDialog1" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">300dp</item>
    <item name="android:scrollX">-10dp</item>
    <item name="android:scrollY">-5dp</item>
</style>
```

EDIT:

I have also tried `android:layout_x` and `android:layout_y`, but no use!

This is the one that I have
![enter image description here][1]

but what I really want is which is just below the signup logo positioned at a particular x and y positive!!!!![enter image description here][2]

Comment: The prevailing advice by google is not to change this sort of thing, users have expectations and doing this flags to the user that you've done something non-standard and therefore not up to standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code!

```
LayoutParams lp = this.getWindow().getAttributes();
             lp.x=50;lp.y=20;lp.width=100;lp.height=200;lp.gravity=Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
            lp.dimAmount=0;            
            lp.flags=LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
this.setContentView(view, lp);
```

Comment: Oops, I wanted to use an exclamation.

Comment: PLEASE be sure to call setAttributes() with the new values.  Otherwise you will have cases where some or all of the values you have changed will not be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Don't extend the dialog theme extend the panel theme.

```
<style name="Theme.CustomPanel" parent="@android:style/Theme.Panel">        
         <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
         <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    </style>
```

This creates a window similar to a dialog except it doesn't center it like a dialog does.  Then create an activity like you normally would then start it.

To make it 5px from left and 10px from top just put padding on your layout

```
 <!-- res/layout/your_layout.xml -->
   <FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:paddingTop="10px"
  android:paddingLeft="5px"></FrameLayout>
```

And of course your activity should just be normal like

```
public class NonCenteredDialogActivity extends Activity{
      protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
          super.onCreate(bundle);
          setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
      }
    }
```