# Set Android Dialog Activity Position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I'm a new freshman from china. I want to make a android dialog activity at the top of screen.

I have setted the style as this:

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.InputAddressDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">top</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">top</item>
</style>
```

The dialog activity appears at the center of vertical but not the top. Anybody can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: doesn't work is not enough to say anything . tell what exact problem you are facing if its a crash share log . my first guess is layout_height missing . so resulting as crash

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478417/positon-an-acitvity-applied-with-a-theme-dialog-at-a-particular-x-y-position ?

Comment: @johnjiang If that worked please post an answer to your own question with the  code you used and then mark it as correct so the question will become answered and you can also help others that may look for this in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve this problem as following.

```
LayoutParams lp = this.getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    lp.dimAmount = 0;
    lp.flags = LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
            | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.input_address, null);
    setContentView(ll, lp);
```